# Perl: Finding maximum then divide by the max value, by comparing value vs by array position

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, max

I want to normalize my data. I wrote this code:

```
my $max1=0;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#data; $i++) {
  if ($data[$i][1]>$data[$max1][1]) {$max1=$i;}
  #Disabled# if ($data[$i][1]>$max1) {$max1=$data[$i][1];}
}

for (my $i=0; $i<=$#data; $i++) {
  print "$i\t$data[$i][0]\t$data[$i][1]\t$max1\t";
  $data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / $data[$max1][1] * 10000;
  #Disabled# $data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / $max1 * 10000;
  print "$data[$i][0]\t$data[$i][1]\t$max1\n";
}
```

However this produced an error: All values up to the max position are divided by the max value, while values after the max position are unchanged, as if " / $data[$max1][1] * 10000 " never occured.

But, if I change the comparison using value rather than by array position, I got the correct results:

```
my $max1=0;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#data; $i++) {
  #Disabled# if ($data[$i][1]>$data[$max1][1]) {$max1=$i;}
  if ($data[$i][1]>$max1) {$max1=$data[$i][1];}
}

for (my $i=0; $i<=$#data; $i++) {
  print "$i\t$data[$i][0]\t$data[$i][1]\t$max1\t";
  #Disabled# $data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / $data[$max1][1] * 10000;
  $data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / $max1 * 10000;
  print "$data[$i][0]\t$data[$i][1]\t$max1\n";
}
```

What did I do wrong with the first bit of code?

Comment: I think we need some sample input data and desired output to be able to tell you. This looks .... messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that, part way through modifying the array, the value of `$i` will be equal to `$max1`. That means the statememt

```
$data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / $data[$max1][1] * 10000
```

will be equivalent to

```
$data[$max1][1] = $data[$max1][1] / $data[$max1][1] * 10000
```

which sets `$data[$i][1]` to 10,000. Thereafter, you are doing

```
 $data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / 10000 * 10000
```

which leaves the values unchanged

The solution, if you need one, is to extract the maximum value into a separate variable before the loop to keep it safe from modification

```
my $maxval =  $data[$i][1]
```

and change the assignment to

```
 $data[$i][1] = $data[$i][1] / $maxval * 10000
```

Your second attempt works correctly because it does exactly this, keeping the factor safe in `$max1`